# Do something if RxJs subject's refCount drops to zero

Tags: rxjs, observable

I'm working on a service layer that manages subscriptions.

I provide subject-backed observables to consumers like this:

```
const subject = new Subject();
_trackedSubjects.push(subject);
return subject.asObservable();
```

Different consumers may monitor the channel, so there may be several observables attached to each subject.

I'd like to monitor the count of `subject.observers` and if it ever drops back to 0, do some cleanup in my library.

I have looked at refCount, but this only is available on Observable.

I'd love to find something like:

```
subject.onObserverCountChange((cur, prev) =>
  if(cur === 0 && prev !== 0) { cleanUp(subject) }
)
```

Is there a way to automatic cleanup like this on a subject?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Subject` - you should probably describe setup/cleanup logic when creating observable. See the example:

```js
const { Observable } = rxjs; // = require("rxjs")
const { share } = rxjs.operators; // = require("rxjs/operators")

const eventSource$ = Observable.create(o => {
  console.log('setup');
  let i = 0
  const interval = setInterval(
    () => o.next(i++),
    1000
  );

  return () => {
    console.log('cleanup');
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
});
const events$ = eventSource$.pipe(share());

const first = events$.subscribe(e => console.log('first: ', e));
const second = events$.subscribe(e => console.log('second: ', e));

setTimeout(() => first.unsubscribe(), 3000);
setTimeout(() => second.unsubscribe(), 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.2.2/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```